# Correct proof of multiplicative limit law?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to prove that if  $\lim_{x \to a} f\left(x \right) = l$ and
$\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = m$ we have $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) = l\cdot m$.

**Proof:**
Let $\epsilon   > 0$ arbitrary. We have
\begin{align*}
  &|f(x)g(x)-l\cdot m| = |f(x)g(x) - l\cdot m + f(x)\cdot m - f(x)\cdot m|
  \\[15pt]
  &=  |f(x)(g(x)-m) + m(f(x)-l)| \le  |f(x)(g(x)-m)| + |m(f(x)-l)|
  \\[15pt]
  &= |f(x)|\cdot  |g(x)-m| + |m|\cdot  |f(x)-l|
 .\end{align*}
By assumption there exists some $\delta _1> 0$ s.t. $|f(x)-m| < \epsilon _1$
for $\epsilon _1 = \min\left\{ \dfrac{\epsilon}{|m|},\epsilon \right\}  $
and $x \in (a-\delta _1, a+\delta _1)$.
We can estimate the factor $|f(x)|$ as follows:
\begin{align}
  |f(x)| = |f(x) - l + l| \le |f(x) - l| + |l|
 .\end{align}
and  hence obtain
\begin{align*}
  |f(x)|\cdot  |g(x)-m| + |m|\cdot  |f(x)-l|
  \le  &|f(x) - l|\cdot |g(x)-m|
  \\[15pt]
  &+ |l|\cdot |g(x)-m|+
  |m|\cdot  |f(x)-l|
 .\end{align*}
As before, there exists some $\delta _2 > 0$ s.t.
$|g(x)-m| < \epsilon _2$ with $\epsilon _2=  
 \min\left\{\dfrac{\epsilon}{|l|},\epsilon \right\} $
so choosing $\delta_3 = \min\left\{\delta_1, \delta_2 \right\} $
we get for $x \in (a-\delta_3, a+\delta_3)$
\begin{align*}
  \underbrace{|f(x)-l|}_{\displaystyle < \epsilon} 
  \underbrace{|g(x)-m|}_{\displaystyle < \epsilon} 
  + \underbrace{|l|\cdot |g(x)-m|}_{\displaystyle < \epsilon} 
  + \underbrace{|m|\cdot |f(x)-l|}_{\displaystyle < \epsilon} 
  < \epsilon^2 +  2\epsilon
 .\end{align*}
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary the corollary follows.
Does my proof seem correct?

Comment: second paragraph you write $|f(x)-m|$ which I guess should be $|f(x)-l|$

Comment: @peek-a-boo you are correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is mostly fine, but here are some issues:

- In your definition of limits, is it a punctured neighborhood ($0<|x-a|<\delta$) or is it a full neighborhood ($|x-a|<\delta$, i.e equivalently $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$)? I suggest you check again with your textbook, because different books have different definitions (though punctured neighborhoods make more sense to me).
- You introduce $\frac{\epsilon}{|m|}$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{|l|}$, but the issue is the denominators could be $0$, so you should introduce something like $\frac{\epsilon}{1+|m|}$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{1+|l|}$. This is fine because $|m|\frac{\epsilon}{1+|m|}<\epsilon$, so all your estimates still work.
- If you have proven that $x\mapsto x^2$ is a continuous function (at the origin), then your proof is fine, because you finished off with $\epsilon^2+2\epsilon$, which approaches $0$ as $\epsilon\to 0^+$. On the other hand, if you havent proven that $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous at the origin, then I would suggest you be more explicit and say in the beginning that we may WLOG assume $0<\epsilon<1$. Then, in the end you can finish off with $\cdots <\epsilon^2+\epsilon < \epsilon+2\epsilon=3\epsilon$

Also, it looks like you're not entirely concerned with having "a perfect $<\epsilon$" at the end of your calculation. I assume you've already proven some theorems which assert that this is fine. If yes, then I would suggest the following shortening of the proof:

> Let $\epsilon>0$. By our assumption there exist $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$, we have $|f(x)-l|<\min(1,\epsilon)$. Similarly, there is a $\delta_2>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$ implies $|g(x)-m|<\min(1,\epsilon)$. Now, let $0<|x-a|<\delta:=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Then,
> \begin{align}
> |f(x)g(x)-lm|&\leq |f(x)|\cdot|g(x)-m|+|m|\cdot|f(x)-l|\\
> &\leq (1+|l|)\cdot\epsilon+|m|\cdot \epsilon\\
> &=(1+|l|+|m|)\epsilon.
> \end{align}
> Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof.

Comment: very good feedback, thanks a lot!